# DC-DC converter with variable input voltage design

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I want to design a DC-DC converter that has a variable input voltage range of 15-40V with an adjustable output voltage capable of supplying 20W. Outputs would range between 3.3V and 12V. I would prefer to not have any programmable devices and to be able to change the output voltage by swapping components.

I have been looking to using switching regulators, but I feel the variable input voltage causes potential stability issues since the inductor value for a buck is determined by the input voltage. To be clear the input voltage would not change while enabled, but I could use any voltage between 15-40V to power the regulator without changing the circuit.

I would like to know if there is a better DC-DC topology I should look into for these requirements?

Comment: It would always be stepping down. 3.3V - 12V is the output voltage range. the lower end it what I was worried about, like if the 40V input was used to get the 3.3V out the duty cycle would have to be very low.

Comment: Potentially of interest: [Designing a DC-DC converter with adjustable voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/474965).

Comment: *I was worried about 40 V input [to] get the 3.3 V* Rightly so, especially if demanding full 6 A: switch needs to stand input voltage and output current, input capacitor a considerable current ripple.

Comment: "the inductor value for a buck is determined by the input voltage". Please _edit your question_ to cite the source for that (a link is best, but a book citation will work.  Include a quote of the actual text that you feel claims that).  While you're editing, please justify the comment "but I feel the variable input voltage causes potential stability issues".  Why should that cause stability issues?  There's plenty of wide input range buck converters out there, so your assertions lack weight.

Comment: The inductor value changing with input voltage is common among buck converts, not a claim. For instance if you look at a buck converter datasheet like the AP64501 below they give you a formula to determine the appropriate Inductor Value, which uses Vin as an input.

https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64501.pdf

Also changing Vin has an impact on phase margin which indicates how stable the control loop for the regulator is.